# connector for male usb A plug not on PCB

Tags: pcb, usb, connector, interconnect

I have a PCB that needs 5V input and I want to plug my contraption(PCB + battery in a housing) into a USB power receptacle. The housing has a male USB A plug popping out perpendicular to the PCB and I am trying to look for a connector to connect the male USB A connections to my PCB. I am not entirely sure what such a connector is called. Do you have any suggestions on how to get power to my PCB from the USB? 
EDIT: This [image: diagram] illustrates it better I guess

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?  Which housing has "male USB A"? Where is your "USB power receptacle"? Where do you expect the power from? A "contraption" definitely needs more elaboration. Schematic and/or pictures please.

Comment: If it's *not on PCB*, then what will it be on?

Comment: The male USB A is on the housing, I added a diagram, hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Still unclear what you are asking about. Is it for power only, or USB data is involved? If you are asking how to wire a male plug embedded  to your housing to some inner PCB, just solder two wires. If you need this connection detachable, any two-pin connector will do the job. Where is the problem?

Comment: Also the whole idea of this contraption is confusing. Do you plan to plug the whole thingy into USB/laptop port directly?

Comment: Typically what people who are doing this do is get a wiremount connector and capture it in the housing details, or else put an additional small PCB there to host a PCB mount connector, possibly vertical rather than right angle.

Comment: Apologies if this is still unclear, but I want to plug this into the wall usb receptacle, hence the perpendicular mounting. Yes I only need 5V input, not data. So I think I will need to make a male USB A PCB with a connector mount that sits perpendicular to the main PCB in the housing and use a connector(JST type?) that connects the two PCBs.

Comment: Look-up *bulkhead mounted [type A or B, male or female] USB connector*.  What you are looking for may or may not exists on the market.  If you really need that type and gender, you can design your own small bulkhead-mounted PCB.  Then you can use any PCB-mounted connector on that board.

Comment: Finally it is clear what do you mean. Final question: is it for one-time DIY project, or do you plan some production out of this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay. The vertical-mount Type-A plug doesn't exist to my experience. You have two basic options:

1. Use a right-angle cable, cut it, and solder wires to your PCB. You may need some mechanical attachment of the right-angle end to your enclosure, glue or something.

[image]

2. Use a surface-mount Type-A plug,

[image]

and fit it vertically. You might need to place your PCB closer to the bottom wall of your enclosure, and make some mechanical reinforcement like an additional square metal housing, solder the housing to PCB, and to few spots on the USB plug shroud.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using data communication then how you connect the plug to PCB is absolutely not important, assuming the wires you use can carry the current and are flexible enough to not break when plug moves in-out.

If you don't want to simply solder the wires to PCB you can use any connector salvaged from old electronic devices, for example cooling fan plug and corresponding pin header from motherboard.

As for actual plug, I'd like to suggest using any cheap USB memory stick like on the photos below. Pop it open, solder your wires, make sure they move freely. Then glue the memory stick inside your enclosure so that it becomes part of the "contraption". This way you won't have to invent your own "popping-out" mechanism.

[image]

[image]